# Showing something is a maximal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\varphi:R\to S$ be an onto ring homomorphism.  Suppose $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, and let $N=\{\varphi(m)|m\in M\}$.  Show that $N$ is a maximal ideal of $S$.  Assume that $N$ is an ideal of $S$, so we only need to show that $N$ is maximal.

I missed this day in class, and it is in the class notes. I wanted to know what the proof was this problem (part of in-class work that was not turned in).

Comment: What characterizations do you have of maximal ideals?

Comment: Can you show that $R/M\cong S/N$?

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to remember when proving $N$ is an ideal is that $\phi:R\to S$ is an **onto** ring homomorphism. So, when checking the ideal axioms, you can assume straight away that the things you are looking at look like $\phi(m)$ and $\phi(m')$ and $\phi(r)$ for some $m,m'\in M$ and $r\in R$, and you can proceed to check whether or not the sum of the first two is in $N$, and whether or not the product with $\phi(r)$ is in $N$ as well.

To check that it's maximal, you can use the fact that the preimage of an ideal is an ideal. By preimage of an ideal $J$ in $S$, I mean $\{r\in R\mid \phi(r)\in J\}$. Suppose $J$ contains $N$. Show that the preimage of $J$ contains $M$, and then consider the two possibilities.

Basically, this last paragraph is just an unpacking of the correspondence isomorphism theorem for rings. Basically, you would apply it to $R/\ker\phi$. If you are familiar with that, then it would be good to prove it that way too.

Comment: The preimage of an ideal is always an ideal, I think you meant that the *image* of an ideal is an ideal (given that $\phi$ is onto.)

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Hm of course... now what direction did I read this question again...?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Thanks for the wake-up call. Some synapses must have misfired while I was typing.